# Reading a Text File from a .jar

Tags: java, eclipse, file, jar

I want to add a text file to my project and read it in a jar file and in eclipse as well. My code for doing so is this:

```
    InputStream fx = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("PlayerStats.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(fx);
```

I've already did this for loading an imageIcon and it's working fine, but when I run it it gets me this error:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException 
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:61)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:55)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:590)
    at Player.<init>(Player.java:16)
    at Main.main(Main.java:6)"
```

=====================================================================

My directory is this:

->Project 
---->src(source code) 
-------->(default package) 
------------>...list of classes... 
---->resources(source folder) 
-------->PlayerStats.txt 
-------->...Images...

The images work fine using the same method:

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("bg.png"));
```

The only difference is that I use this methods in different classes, but they are all in the same source folder("src").

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried using `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/PlayerStats.txt")`

Comment: Yes, I have. The outcome is the same. I still get the same error.

Comment: Have you unzipped the resulting Jar file to make sure that the file exists within the Jar file and exists within the location you are expecting?  Is the name the same (it must match EXACTLY)

Comment: Yes. The file exits along with the other resource files and classes. The filename matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(yourFileName).getFile());
```

if doesn't work put the resources folder inside src folder

Comment: It now works when compiling in the IDE, but when I export to a .jar file it doesn't read the file. Maybe because it's not a file when in .jar? Do I have to convert the resource into an input stream?

Comment: I converted the resource into an InputStream and now works! Both in the Eclipse and in a .jar. Thanks!